# Generate random object for testing in NodeJs based on interface

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, unit-testing

I have a set of typescript interfaces that describe a complex object (with some arrays and sub-interfaces).
What NodeJs package can be used to generate fake data in all required fields?

Comment: Faker.js should work, it can be npm installed

Comment: I could not find a method there that works with interfaces.

Comment: Could you post some of the code?, it's not quite clear where you're using the fake data.

Comment: it is very simple - I have a bunch of Interfaces defined with some fields inside and would like to get a fake object with these fields filled with something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Afaik there's no package that is able to generate dummy-json from a typescript interface.

You can, however, use [typescript-json-schema](https://github.com/YousefED/typescript-json-schema) to generate json-schema from your typescript interface, which you then can pass to [json-schema-faker](https://github.com/json-schema-faker/) to generate the dummy-json.